# Having a problem with making this function typescript conform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

So I have this code:

```
import * as Icons from "../../icons"

const Icon = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  const Icon = Icons[icon]
  return <Icon {...props} />
}
```

and I am trying to find the correct types for it but no matter what I do, it won´t work.
Pls HELP

### My errors:

[image]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an interface for the `Icons` import by `import * as Icons from './icons'` statement.

`./icons/SquareIcon.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function SquareIcon() {
  return <div>square icon</div>;
}
```

`./icons/CycleIcon.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function CycleIcon() {
  return <div>cycle icon</div>;
}
```

`./icons/index.ts`:

```
import CycleIcon from './CycleIcon';
import SquareIcon from './SquareIcon';

export interface IconType {
  cycle: typeof CycleIcon;
  square: typeof SquareIcon;
}

export { CycleIcon as cycle, SquareIcon as square };
```

`Icon.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Icons from './icons';
import type { IconType } from './icons';

const Icon = ({ icon, ...props }: { icon: keyof IconType }) => {
  const Icon = Icons[icon];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

function Test() {
  return <Icon icon="cycle"></Icon>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the data types as follows,

```
const Icon = ({ icon , ...props } : {icon : string , props : any}) => {
    const Icon = Icons[icon]
    return <Icon {...props} />
}
```

If the data has only one type you can use the proper data type without using any.

Comment: thanks, but I still get the Element "implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof"  error in the second line of code.

Comment: what is the data type of icon param. Is it a number

Comment: the type is string

Comment: did you try replacing any with string for icon param ?

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("")'.

Comment: I think you are trying to import a set of icons at once from your import statement?